# How to set a callable function to AutoField default attribute?

Tags: django, django-models, parameters, default

I'm trying to overwrite the pk of my models to use a random generator.

Here's the model field:

```py
pk = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, verbose_name='ID', default=genkey)
```

and the keygenerator:

```py
def genkey():
    return random.randrange(1,142857)
```

So, I would like to make the autofield to execute the `genkey` function as much as possible until it gets a non-used key. Is there an attribute that I didn't find or do I need to code it in the generator (by getting all the used keys) ?

My main goal is to make a generator as generic as possible, not define a custom generator for each model.

Comment: BUt the idea of an `AutoField` is that the *database* will automatically create an id.

Comment: I know, it can be an `IntegerField` or whatever, I use here `AutoField` because it is the default pk field type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making some research and tests, I ended up creating a class.

```py
class RandomIDKey(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(
        auto_created=True,
        primary_key=True,
        serialize=False,
        verbose_name='ID',
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
        editable=False
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.id = genkey(type(self))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

with a public function:

```py
def genkey(model):
    generated_key = random.randrange(1, 2147483648)
    if model.objects.filter(pk=generated_key).exists():
        generated_key = genkey(model)
    return generated_key
```

Using an AutoField is a bad idea since the field is not auto-generated by the database, hence the IntegerField

Answer (score 0):

An [**`AutoField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) is, like the documentation says:

> **An `IntegerField` that automatically increments according to available IDs**. You usually won't need to use this directly; a primary key field will automatically be added to your model if you don’t specify otherwise.

It is thus an [**`IntegerField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField), and we thus can simply use an `IntegerField` instead, llike:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    pk = models.IntegerField(editable=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True, verbose_name='ID', default=genkey)
    # ...
```

So specifying a default on an `AutoField` is a bit in contradiction with what an `AutoField` does. If you make an `IntegerField` with [**`editable=False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable), to ensure that, at least by default, it will not be included in a `ModelForm`. This is in essence what a primary key does.

Comment: Why does it need to be blank=True? The default is set on instantiation, so the field will never be blank.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: you don't need to set it `blank=True`, but the `AutoField` sets it blank (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L906). Likely because otherwise it will apear in a `ModelForm`, whereas a pk usually is not something a user is supposed to create/update.

Comment: No, that's because as you say AutoField doesn't have a default, it's set by the db on save, so if blank is False then the model will never be valid. That's not the case here, where we do have a default.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: hmmm... yes. Perhaps `editable=False` is better then?